# SQL Query for fetching the 11th,22th,33th, row from tha table

Tags: sql

I want to fetch the data of a table as a multiple of 11 like 11,22,33,44 and so on..by sql query

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: have you unique id autoincrement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `mod` function:

```
select * from table_name where table_name.id mod 11 = 0;
```

Comment: There can be gaps in the ID sequence and then this is not working

Comment: True that @juergend thanks for the addition! But the main question is to get the every 11th row :)

Comment: Exactly, and not the rows with the ids 11,22,... which can be totally different ones

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MySQL you can do

```
select * from
(
   select *, @rank := @rank + 1 as rank
   from your_table
   cross join (select @rank := 0) r
   order by id
) tmp
where rank % 11 = 0
```